# Increase PermGen space (Tomcat7, Windows Service)

Tags: java, windows, tomcat

I'm running Tomcat7 as a service on a Windows 2008 Server
and from time to time I get the "OutOfMemory Exception" due to the PermGen space.

I read in another thread that using a setenv.bat doesnt work when running Tomcat as a service (because catalina.bat is not used, hope thats correct). I usually use the "Configure Tomcat" GUI to set the memory pool for Java (min, max), but there is not specific option for the Perm space as far as I can see.

Can I set that value in the Java Options field of the GUI somehow? Or how do I do that?

Regards
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like this is what you are looking for:

http://umpteenchoices.blogspot.com/2011/05/tomcat-7-windows-service-memory.html

As per the link:

To set the Permgen size, you need either -XX:PermSize=XXXm or -XX:MaxPermSize=XXXm. This can be set on the Java tab of the Monitor Tomcat GUI, this time as a Java Option.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Yes you could set that in the jvm options field for example

```
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
```

For the case that your problem exists (but only comes up later) then you should profile your application for memory leaks.